# Using a bash script to dynamically generate another bash script and run it

Tags: linux

Is there a way to generate a Bashscript dynamically using a Bashscript, change the mod of the generated Bashscript to allow execution, and then run the generated Bashscript?

Comment: I'm not sure about a `Bashscript`, although in `Bash` it's possible to create a `script`, if attempted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes it is totally feasible!

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/tmp/generated.bash"

cat <<END > $FILE
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello There from generated script!" 
END

chmod 755 $FILE
echo "running ...."
$FILE
echo "done"
```

gonna give you the output like :

```
[tmp]=> ./test.bash
running ....
Hello There from generated script!
done
```